# Supporting apocalypse

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, apocalypse, social-norms

Let's define some basic principles of my world:

- It takes place within a very small galaxy.
- *Very limited FTL* - escaping from the galaxy is practically impossible, and planets are connected by ancient teleport gates.
- Every single planet (*excluding* gas giants) has one of this device.
- There's a **special** teleport gate somewhere within the galaxy, that can provide teleportation to the outside (assume ideal circumstances, so it's not only safe but highly desired to use)
- Said special gate is connected to the other gates, and indirectly, to the planets themselves. (the method itself is complicated)
- Connection is fully established only after hundreds of thousands of years, but then, it can be activated at any time.
- Said activation event drains various levels of energy from *every* planet. By this, I mean quite a lot of possible outcomes, but it's undesired either way: natural disasters, mass death of living beings, and so on.

**TL;DR: in my world, you can escape your galaxy if you're in the right place and right time, but it inevitably kills billions of other beings, including very sentient ones.**

Assume there's a bunch of people who are simply unconvinceable to stay within the galaxy and definitely want to escape through that very teleport. Deconstructing this issue, it can be *very* clear that a gigantic majority of sentient beings (practically everyone who cares about his/her/its safety in the galaxy) would oppose to any organization that would try to activate this device.

What factors can contribute to a society, army, gang or any other structured unit of individuals to support activating this device? In short, **why would any organization support bringing apocalypse, even at the risk of their own lives?**

*The rules of WBSE does not permit asking about the motivation of individuals, so examine this issue on the level of organized structures of individal beings, primarily humans.*

Comment: If the vast majority of beings would be negatively affected and violently disagree with the use of this device, why are they not taking steps to disconnect or deactivate it?

Comment: @Thucydides because it's impossible.

Answer (score 1):

**Doomsday Cults**

There are any number of [Doomsday Cults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_cult) now that would want to trigger the gate just for the sake of triggering the gate or to destroy/"save" all non-believers.

Modern/Near-Current examples that one can reasonably assume would trigger such a device intentionally include:

- [Aum Shinrikyo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aum_Shinrikyo)
- [Branch Davidians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_Davidians)
- [The Order of the Solar Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Solar_Temple)

And even groups like [The Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant (ISIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_State_of_Iraq_and_the_Levant) could be fairly counted as people that have no problem killing anyone not already part of their group.

It seems certain that additional religious groups would pop up with the express purpose of triggering the gate if it was known about.

Comment: Not sure if ISIL is a proper example; it would be true only if they have no care about their "global" safety. Sure, they do not care about their personal safety, or even the safety of their neighbourhood - but I doubt they would risk an action that can put the very existence of the state itself into danger. (but it's rather a question of actual politics, than worldbuilding)

Comment: @Katamori - I suppose that is true, or at least potentially true.  As things get worse for them and their territory starts to collapse though I'd definitely be on the watch for a group of them heading to that gateway to trigger it.

Answer (score 1):

**For an underdog to gain power**

Throughout history, human organizations have pursued profoundly destructive actions, in the belief they might gain a relative advantage over their enemies.

The more disenfranchised an organization might be, the greater the chance that it will "lose less" than the groups which currently dominate.

Here are some of the major scenarios where an organization might hope to improve its standing:

- Revolution -- if the existing power base is weak, a power-hungry
  group might hope to use the crisis to topple it
- Terrorism -- a strong
  power base might not fail, but an organization might hope to weaken
  or punish it
- Bounty -- organizations might receive handsome payment
  for their assistance to the escapees
- Ransom -- organizations might
  demand payment to thwart the escape, or even create a 'highest
  bidder' scenario
- Spoils -- an organization might hope to capture or
  compete for territory/property the escapees have abandonned

Answer (score 1):

## For space habitats we go

For motivating civilizations and groups to move from planets to space habitats. Pure ethical reasons for such decisions in form preventing them all from risk of extinction by natural causes like meteorites and supernovas, launched by not named forces.
For economical reasons, to exchange technology of such constructions, in form let them known that they are possible and they are more comfortable then planets.

It will free planets for other usages, like using their mass as construction materials for mega projects, because heavy elements amount is less then few percent of total mass of matter in universe. 98% is Hydrogen and helium, [Abundance in the Universe of the elements](http://periodictable.com/Properties/A/UniverseAbundance.html)

For which purposes they need that material, maybe for fixing their gates, probably because of that at current state they present some danger for all live in galaxy (specially for humans)
So it is possibly that human politics is involved, to use it to convince their citizen to move in to space to live.

Comment: In fact, I already created an organization similar to this - you quite nailed it :D